# AutoTabbing between textareas when max length is reached

Tags: python, html, reactjs, textarea, plotly-dash

I am building an application with dash and need to automatically move from one textarea (or input if that would work better) to another when the maximum length is reached in the prior textarea without having to click on the new textarea or push the tab button.

Here is the html.Div with the textarea components that I need to tab through automatically.

```
html.Div(
                        style = {
                            'display': 'flex',
                            'width': '90%',
                            'margin-left': '1.7%',
                            'backgroundColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                            'borderColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                            'margin-top': '7%',
                        },
                        children = [
                            dcc.Textarea(
                                value = 'MRN - Ep',
                                readOnly = True,
                                style = {
                                    'textAlign': 'center', 
                                    'color': '#636E72',
                                    'width': '30%',
                                    'height': 80,
                                    'font-family': 'font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif',
                                    'font-size': '40px',
                                    'borderColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                                    'border-radius': '25px',
                                    'background-color': 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                                    'font-weight': 'bold',
                                    'margin-top': '5%',
                                    'margin-left': '-6.5%',
                                    'overflow': 'auto',
                                    'outline': 'none',
                                    '-webkit-box-shadow': 'none',
                                    '-moz-box-shadow': 'none',
                                    'box-shadow': 'none',
                                },
                            ),
                            html.Textarea(
                                id = 'mrnInput1',
                                placeholder = '', 
                                maxLength = 1, 
                                autoFocus = True,
                                style = {
                                    'color': '#636E72',
                                    'width': '6%',
                                    'height': 100,
                                    'font-family': 'font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif',
                                    'font-size': '40px',
                                    'borderColor': '#DFE6E9',
                                    'backgroundColor': '#F6FBFF',
                                    'font-weight': 'light',
                                    'margin-left': '-4.5%',
                                    'margin-top': '2.8%',
                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                },            
                            ),
                            html.Textarea(
                                id = 'mrnInput2',
                                placeholder = '',
                                maxLength = 1, 
                                style = {
                                    'color': '#636E72',
                                    'width': '6%',
                                    'height': 100,
                                    'font-family': 'font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif',
                                    'font-size': '40px',
                                    'borderColor': '#DFE6E9',
                                    'backgroundColor': '#F6FBFF',
                                    'font-weight': 'light',
                                    'margin-left': '2%',
                                    'margin-top': '2.8%',
                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                },            
                            ),
                            html.Textarea(
                                id = 'mrnInput3',
                                placeholder = '',
                                maxLength = 1,  
                                style = {
                                    'color': '#636E72',
                                    'width': '6%',
                                    'height': 100,
                                    'font-family': 'font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif',
                                    'font-size': '40px',
                                    'borderColor': '#DFE6E9',
                                    'backgroundColor': '#F6FBFF',
                                    'font-weight': 'light',
                                    'margin-left': '2%',
                                    'margin-top': '2.8%',
                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                },            
                            ),
                            html.Textarea(
                                id = 'mrnInput4',
                                placeholder = '', 
                                maxLength = 1, 
                                style = {
                                    'color': '#636E72',
                                    'width': '6%',
                                    'height': 100,
                                    'font-family': 'font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif',
                                    'font-size': '40px',
                                    'borderColor': '#DFE6E9',
                                    'backgroundColor': '#F6FBFF',
                                    'font-weight': 'light',
                                    'margin-left': '2%',
                                    'margin-top': '2.8%',
                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                },            
                            ),
                            html.Textarea(
                                id = 'mrnInput5',
                                placeholder = '',
                                maxLength = 1, 
                                style = {
                                    'color': '#636E72',
                                    'width': '6%',
                                    'height': 100,
                                    'font-family': 'font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif',
                                    'font-size': '40px',
                                    'borderColor': '#DFE6E9',
                                    'backgroundColor': '#F6FBFF',
                                    'font-weight': 'light',
                                    'margin-left': '2%',
                                    'margin-top': '2.8%',
                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                },            
                            ),
                            html.Textarea(
                                id = 'mrnInput6',
                                placeholder = '',
                                maxLength = 1, 
                                style = {
                                    'color': '#636E72',
                                    'width': '6%',
                                    'height': 100,
                                    'font-family': 'font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif',
                                    'font-size': '40px',
                                    'borderColor': '#DFE6E9',
                                    'backgroundColor': '#F6FBFF',
                                    'font-weight': 'light',
                                    'margin-left': '2%',
                                    'margin-top': '2.8%',
                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                },            
                            ),
                            dcc.Textarea(
                                value = '-',
                                readOnly = True,
                                style = {
                                    'textAlign': 'center', 
                                    'color': '#636E72',
                                    'width': '6%',
                                    'height': 100,
                                    'font-family': 'font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif',
                                    'font-size': '80px',
                                    'borderColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                                    'border-radius': '25px',
                                    'background-color': 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                                    'font-weight': 'bold',
                                    'margin-top': '3.5%',
                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                    'overflow': 'auto',
                                    'outline': 'none',
                                    '-webkit-box-shadow': 'none',
                                    '-moz-box-shadow': 'none',
                                    'box-shadow': 'none',
                                },
                            ),
                            html.Textarea(
                                id = 'episodeInput1',
                                placeholder = '',
                                maxLength = '1', 
                                style = {
                                    'color': '#636E72',
                                    'width': '6%',
                                    'height': 100,
                                    'font-family': 'font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif',
                                    'font-size': '40px',
                                    'borderColor': '#DFE6E9',
                                    'backgroundColor': '#F6FBFF',
                                    'font-weight': 'light',
                                    'margin-top': '2.8%',
                                    'textAlign': 'center',
                                },            
                            ),
                        ], 
                    ),
```

I've tried callbacks to manipulate the tabIndex, autoFocus, and accessKey as well as with a separate, imported JS script but have had no success. I have managed to do this in a seperate react project before, but am having no luck with dash-python. I am wondering if anyone has any potential solutions or has figured this out before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [client side callback](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks) to do this.

Here is some simplified example code that demonstrates the idea:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc                                     
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input                          
                                                                     
                                                                     
app = Dash(__name__)                                                 
                                                                     
                                                                     
app.layout = html.Div([                                              
    dcc.Store(id="dummy-output"),                                    
    dcc.Textarea(id="text-area-1", maxLength=1),                 
    dcc.Textarea(id="text-area-2")                               
])                                                                   
                                                                     
                                                                     
app.clientside_callback(                                             
    """                                                              
    function(textAreaValue) {                                        
        if (textAreaValue.length == 1) {                             
            document.getElementById('text-area-2').focus()           
        }                                                            
    }                                                                
    """,                                                             
    Output("dummy-output", "data"),                                  
    Input("text-area-1", "value"),                                   
    prevent_initial_call=True                                        
)                                                                    
                                                                     
                                                                     
if __name__ == '__main__':                                           
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The idea of the code above is to create a client side callback that takes the first text area value as input. Then we check if the length of the text value is equal to your max text length. If that is the case we retrieve the element by its id and call [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) on the html element.

I've used a dummy [dcc.Store](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) as the output.

Adjust acording to your needs.